# telegram server can`t update my bot webhook

Tags: php, nginx, telegram

We have a telegram bot that use a Web-hook to receive updates.
It was fine for like 6 months . after some issue with mod_security blocking our site , the Web-hook stopped working and give us " Connection timed out " in the method " getWebhookInfo " . we ask our hosting to white-list our site for mod_security and they did . we can work with our site and everything is fine again but the web-hook keep getting us " Connection timed out ".it`s like server cached our site and wont`t check it again .

we set our web-hook again with new certificate to make sure everything works fine .

message from `api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getWebhookInfo` is :

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://*****/get","has_custom_certificate":true,"pending_update_count":12,"last_error_date":1495875185,"last_error_message":"Connection timed out","max_connections":40}}

i check the address https://*****/get with postman , send some fake data and its working fine .

Comment: are you resolved your problem? i'm faced now with same error

Comment: @A.Innokentiev yes . i changed the address of webhook and its worked ! it was something like site.com/webhook.php and i changed to site.com/webhook2.php . somehow it worked again !